# Why I get NAN on generator increment?

Tags: javascript

I want increment value of property `"c"` in object `"test"` on every next call but I got `{ value: NaN, done: false }`. Please help me

```js
const test = {
  c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]
};

function* responseDataSet(dataSet, elem) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    const inc = yield dataSet[elem][i]++; // here i try increment
    i = (dataSet[elem].length + i + inc) % dataSet[elem].length;  
  }
}

const launch = responseDataSet(test, 'c');

console.log(launch.next());
```

Comment: `dataSet["c"][0]` is the object `{ a: 1 }`. You cannot increment an object reference.

Comment: you are passing a string "c" into the function but it is a object, so it will be `test.c` not c as string.

Comment: if I'll change  variable inc on `(yield dataSet[elem][i]) === 'prev' ? -1 : 1` it's will work correctly

Comment: but I want the only increment  value  without decrement and condition

Comment: Your use of `yield` is unusual. When you embed it in an expression like that, things only make sense when you pass a parameter to `.next()` so that the value passed will work as the value of the `yield` expression.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `i = (dataSet[elem].length + i + inc) % dataSet[elem].length;`? You are kind of adding an object with a number and divide it by a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix in this way

```
const inc = yield (dataSet[elem][i]['a'])++; // here i try
```

Check result on the following demo.

```js
const test = {
  c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]
};

function* responseDataSet(dataSet, elem) {
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    const inc = yield (dataSet[elem][i]['a'])++; // here i try increment
    i = (dataSet[elem].length + i + inc) % dataSet[elem].length;  
  }
}

const launch = responseDataSet(test, 'c');

console.log(launch.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = {
  c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]
};
```

**`test["c"]`** is an array, and cannot increment an array like a number, when you do so, you get [NaN (Not-A-Number)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Maybe you mean to increment **`test["c"][0]["a"]`** or **`test["c"][1]["a"]`** or **`test["c"][2]["a"]`**